# Is my MIPS program correct?

Tags: assembly, mips

Write a MIPS program that generates and adds up all even numbers from 1 to 100.

- it must have at least one loop
- it should store the sum in register R12

---

And this is what I wrote:

```
main:
    li      $t0, 0               # clear register $t0 to zero
    li      $t4, 0               # clear register $t4 to zero
loop:
    add     $t0, $t0, 2          # generating even numbers in register $t0
    add     $t4, $t4, $t0        #  compute the sume
    bne     $t0, 100, loop       # if t0 reached 100 then go to loop.
    b endloop                    # branch to endloop
endloop:
    li      $v0, 10              # terminate program run and
    syscall                      # Exit
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you run it?  Do you have a MIPS board or an emulator or something?

Comment: I use gxemul to emulate a mips architecture running NETBSD
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GXemul

Comment: Another emulator is qemu, which emulates a bunch of architectures and systems including MIPS.

Comment: thanks...but could you do me a favour, i ran it with spim, but everything looks good, could help me to run it with any emulator to see if i got it correct...thanks

Comment: If it ran with SPIM why would it work differently somewhere else?

Comment: not that it helps, but you spelled "sum" as "sume." (you also have the first two letters of exit capitalized).  In other words, you should do the HW on your own, but I'll help with the spelling and grammar :)

Comment: I also just noticed this, you say that the result of your sum should be put in register r12.  I am not sure that is a valid register.  You also never move the result out of t4.  Maybe you want to look into that.

Comment: @csunwold, i think that register R12 is general purpose register number twelve, which happens to be $t4

Comment: Change the `b endloop` to a `nop`, since execution ends up flowing there immediately after the branch regardless.

Answer (score 10):

I just completed my MIPs assembly class and I have a suggestion for you: **Don't use PC Spim!**

I've used PC Spim, Mars, and Qemu and the best for general course work is the [Mars (Mips Assembler and Runtime Simulator)](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/).  The editor is nice, it crashes *a lot* less and it allows you to easily debug and set breakpoints. It is free, open source and created by Missouri State University.

It comes as a .jar file so you can run it on both Windows and Linux.
[image]
[[Mars Mips Emulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/v3_2_screenshot.jpg)]

In the general case, an easy way to tell if a number is even or odd is to AND (bitwise) 1 with the number and if the result is 0 then the number is even.

However, since we want all the even numbers in a series we can just loop and increment our number by 2 like you did in your posted code.

When adding an immediate value you should use "addi" or "addu" instructions, not "add".  You also said you wanted to put the result in register $r12 but this is not a valid MIPs register.  Check out MIPs wikipedia link to see a list of all the registers: [MIPS - Register Usage.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_Register_Usage)

I've modified your program to work correctly. It stores the final result in $t1 and then prints the final result.

```
                .text
                .globl main
main:
    li      $t0, 0               # $t0 = loop counter
    li      $t1, 0               # $t1 = sum of even numbers
loop:
    addi    $t0, $t0, 2          # generating even numbers in register $t0
    add     $t1, $t1, $t0        #  compute the sum
    bne     $t0, 100, loop       # if t0 reached 100 then go to loop.

    li      $v0, 4
    la      $a0, result
    syscall                      # print out "Sum = "

    li      $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t1
    syscall                      # print out actual sum


exit:
    li      $v0, 10              # terminate program run and
    syscall                      # Exit 


                .data
result:         .asciiz "Sum = "
```

After running this in Mars I get the following:

> Sum = 2550
>   -- program is finished running --

Comment: but is it suppose to add even numbers from 1 to 100?

Comment: @Simucal, I dont think they mean $r12 by R12, but general purpose register 12, which is $t4.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use SPIM yourself.  Also the line "b endloop" is unnecessary because if you don't branch back up to the top of loop the program will "fall into" endloop.  
Download SPIM here:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html

Answer (score 1):

Code looks ok. As cunwold said, the "b endloop" is unnecesary, since the branch target is the first branch (bne...) fallthrough.
There is one mistake though.

You are using the same instruction (add) in two different ways.
The instruction

```
add $t0,$t0,2
```

should be

```
addiu $t0,$t0,2
```

Since you are adding an inmediate, not two registers.

So, here it goes. I replaced the syscall part with an actual return to a function (value returns in $v0 register).

Hope it helps.

File main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int addEven();

int main(){


        printf("%d\n",addEven());
        return 0;
}
```

File addEven.S (assembly)

```
#include <mips/regdef.h>

  /*
   * int addEven();
   * Adds even numbers between 0 and 100.
   * 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 +....+100 = 2550
   */

        .text
        .align 2
        .globl addEven

addEven:
        li      t0,0            # clear register $t0 to zero
        li      t4,0            # clear register $t4 to zero
loop:
        addiu   t0, t0,2          # generating even numbers in register $t0
        add     t4, t4,t0          #  compute the sume (R12 = t4)
        bne     t0, 100, loop      # if t0 reached 100 then go to loop.
endloop:
        move    v0,t4
        jr      ra
```

I compiled and linked these files. Here it goes.

```
root@:~/stackoverflow# gcc -c -g addEven.S
root@:~/stackoverflow# gcc -c -g main.c
root@:~/stackoverflow# gcc main.o addEven.o -o prog 
root@:~/stackoverflow# ./prog 
2550
root@:~/stackoverflow#
```

Comment: Do you use MIPs often in this way?  If so, what do you use it for?  I'm curious because I like MIPs but don't see how I would use it very often.

Comment: I use it quite often, but only for educational purposes. I'm trying to get some boards to take it one step beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html) emulator. When I took Computer Organization, I used SPIM and it was fairly easy to use. You can also find tutorials on MIPS online. Remember, Google is your friend.

Comment: please could you help me to run and see if i got it correct..thanks

Comment: but is it suppose to add even numbers from 1 to 100?